# dba left the company and we do not know the admin password. 3 nodes replica set

Tags: mongodb

We are running 3 nodes replica set (mongo 2.2). Just recently our dba left the company and we do no know the admin password. Can anyone point us to steps to reset the admin password?

This is a QA replica.

We have tried below steps.

Shutdown all 3 nodes.

Bring 1 node without --auth 
 in mongo shell - 
   db.addUser("admin","new_password")

This threw an exception.

430 error: { "$err" : "not authorized for query on admin.system.users", "code" : 16550 } at src/mongo/shell/query.js:128

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you been trying this king of stuff on you database?
 1. Stop mongo instance 
 2. make a copy of your datas
 3. remove auth from lauch script : --auth or --keyfile
 4. start mongo but this time without authentication 
 5. Edit the users rights on mongo
 7. restart mongo with auth (--auth or --keyfile )